# Spring @Validated and @InitBinder

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to validate my form using a Spring validator, with `@Validated`.

However, I'm confused why I need to specify the Validator in an `@InitBinder`.

Here is my relevant code snippets from the controller:

```
@InitBinder("organisationForm")
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new OrganisationFormValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addOrganisation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addOrganisationPost(@Validated @ModelAttribute("organisationForm") OrganisationForm organisationForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "configuration/addOrganisation";
}
```

This works fine but I will need to specify an `@InitBinder` for each of my requests.

Spring has a way of registring all the convertors like so:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
     ConversionServiceFactory.registerConverters(getConverters(), 
     formatterRegistry);
}
```

Is there not a "Validation service" in Spring that looks through all the validators and chooses the right one, perhaps using the `supports` method enforced by the Spring `Validator` interface:

```
public boolean supports(final Class<?> clazz) {
    return OrganisationForm.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

Just seems strange this doesn't exist in Spring. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It seems strange that you don't use a validation framework.

Comment: @zeroflagL I'm using [Spring framework's Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html)

Comment: Sorry, my comment was phrased badly. I meant something like Bean Validation. It's a lot easier imho.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) to add validators to your init Binders and you can specify Model Attributes and ExceptionHandler.

If you want to use validators through out the controller (or through out the specific list of controllers) you can specify controller classes to it by using its attributes.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = { Controller1.class, Controller2.class})
```

Comment: Nice solution but it still requires me to bind the Validators specifically to each binder like `@InitBinder("organisationForm")`. Is there really no way to register all validators and have the `@Validated` use the `Validator` `supports` method to find the right one?

Comment: @Geditdk If you don't want to bind Validators, you can use `jsr 303` validation framework. Implementations provided by both `hibernate` and `spring`